# Laravel : Nested relation search

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two nested relations, One is `requester.link` and `requester.company`, I want both to be search for the word `$request->search`.

The code is self explanatory:

```
$clients = \App\AcceptedConnection::with('requester.link', 'requester.company')
    ->where('accepter_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->orWhereHas('requester.link', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->orWhere('name', $request->search);
    })->orWhereHas('requester.company', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->orWhere('email', $request->search);
        $query->orWhere('firstname', $request->search);
        $query->orWhere('lastname', $request->search);
    })->get();
```

It gives me the records for anything searched, It returns records even the  search is not matching, Search anything and it will give you records,

What am i missing ?

Comment: you have multiple OR condition and if any one of them meet, the record will come

Comment: @AlivetoDie Exactly thats the expected behavior but i am getting records even the search query is not matching.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking whether `accepter_id=Auth::user()->id` OR a record matches your search term.

You have to wrap the `whereHas()` checks into a closure:

```
$clients = \App\AcceptedConnection::with('requester.link', 'requester.company')
    ->where('accepter_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where(function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereHas('requester.link', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->orWhere('name', $request->search);
        })->orWhereHas('requester.company', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->orWhere('email', $request->search);
            $query->orWhere('firstname', $request->search);
            $query->orWhere('lastname', $request->search);
        });
    })->get()
```

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted? This shows other users that the issue is resolved.